# $K$-ranks of some algebraic groups in Lubotzky's "Discrete groups, expanding graphs and invariant measures"

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, arithmetic-geometry, arithmetic-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}\DeclareMathOperator\SO{SO}$Let $G$ be a semisimple algebraic group and $K$ any field. Then
the $K$-rank of $G$ is the maximal rank $r$ of a $K$-splitting
torus $T \cong (K^*)^r $ contained as a subgroup in $G(K)$, the
group of $K$-valued points of $G$.

In Alexander Lubotzky's
['Discrete Groups, Expanding Graphs and Invariant Measures'](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-0346-0332-4)
is claimed without proof on

I) page 27, 2nd line: that for every field $K$,
the $K$-rank of $\SL_n(K) $ is $n-1$

II) page 29, **Example 3.2.4** (B): the $\mathbb{Q}_5$-rank
of $ \SO(n)(\mathbb{Q}_5)$ is $[\frac{n}{2}]$ (due to the text that's since
$x^2 \equiv -1$ has a solution in $\mathbb{Q}_5$)

How to see these two statements? For I) we can obviously
embed for every field $K$ the torus $(K^*)^{(n-1)} $ into $\SL_n(K)$
via $(a_1,..., a_{n-1}) \mapsto 
\operatorname{diag}(a_1,..., a_{n-1}, \frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} a_i})$.
How to show that it's not possible to embed in $\SL_n(K)$ somehow a torus of bigger rank?

On II) I have no clue how to exploit that the
congruence relation $x^2 \equiv_5 -1$ has a solution in
$\mathbb{Q}_5$, to conclude that the rank of
$ \SO(n)(\mathbb{Q}_5)$ is $[\frac{n}{2}]$.

Comment: For 1: The set of diagonal elements is its own centraliser. Therefore, there is no bigger abelian subgroup. For 2: Find a torus, that does the job, I guess that the quadratic space decomposes into a sum of hyperbolic spaces (see Scharlau's book on quadratic forms). Then compare it to the case $K=\mathbb C$. If over the complex field, there is no bigger torus, you've got it.

Comment: 2. By this congruence you may generate isotropic vectors (and subspaces, essentially by choosing $(x_{1},\ldots, x_{n/2}, ix_{1},\ldots, ix_{n/2})$... Anyhow, this is not a research level question...

Comment: By definition, a split torus $T$ over $K$ is diagonalizable over the given field $K$. For the special linear group, a torus $T\subseteq \text{SL}_n(K)$ has diagonal matrices of determinant $1$ and therefore its last entry is determined as you wrote (the inverse of the products of the $n-1$ previous ones).  For the special orthogonal group ones has to consider the even case $\text{SO}_n$ and the odd case $\text{SO}_{n-1}$. In the even case the maximal torus is given as a block-diagonal matrices with blocks of size $2\times 2$ each one a rotation in dimension $2$. This gives the rank as $n$ . .

Comment: For the odd case the torus is the same adjusting its action about a fixed axis. The hypothesis ensures that $\sqrt{-1}\in{\mathbb Q}_5$ and hence you work as you will do with ${\mathbb C}$ and the rotations are diagonalizable.

Comment: In my first comment above, the even case is $\text{SO}_{2n}$ of course, and the odd case is $\text{SO}_{2n+1}$